# Windows. Setting user permissions on usb peripherals

Tags: windows, permissions, usb

At work, I finally got the right to have a Debian installed into a Virtualbox on a Windows XP host.

The USB access does not work in my Debian because it requires authorization from the system admin and I can't have admin rights to my Windows.

Our sys admin (not too well trained and systematically trying to stall me in my projects) says he can't grant me access to the usb devices on the Debian without also giving me full admin access on my Windows.

Is it true or is it BS? (or, he does not know how to do it). I don't know a thing about permissions on Windows but the bare minimum, I just know that on Linux, they can be finely tuned.

Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a programming question, but yes, devices also have ACLs. Check out the WinObj tool from Sysinternals.